# Laravel: extra field sync with array

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization

Im trying to save data inside a pivot table with an extra field called data.

when i save i have this array:

```
 [
     5 => "files"
     4 => "pictures"
     3 => "tags"
     1 => "thumbs"
 ]
```

My table looks like this:

- project_id
- option_id
- name

The ids shown above refer to option_id and the string to name inside the database.

When i try to use sync like this: $project->options()->sync($data);

$data is the array shown above

Im getting a error thats its trying to save the option_id with "files".

Here is how i build up the data that i use for sync:

Im trying to get what you suggested but dont know how to achieve it:

here is how i build up the array:

```
foreach($request->input('option_id') as $id) {
    $option['option_id'][] = $id;
    $option['data'][] = $request->input('data')[$id];
}

$data = array_combine($option['option_id'], $option['data']);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is covered in the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations):

> Adding Pivot Data When Syncing
>
> You may also associate other pivot table values with the given IDs:
>
> ```
> $user->roles()->sync(array(1 => array('expires' => true)));
> ```

In your example, you would have to change your array to look something like below but I believe this would translate to:

```
$data = [
     5 => [ 'name' => "files"    ],
     4 => [ 'name' => "pictures" ],
     3 => [ 'name' => "tags"     ],
     1 => [ 'name' => "thumbs"   ], 
 ];

$project->options()->sync($data);
```

I believe you may also need to modify how your `Project` model relates itself to your `Options` model:

```
// File: app/model/Project.php
public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Option')->withPivot('name');
}
```

This is also noted in the linked-to manual page:

> By default, only the keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship.

**Update**

Try creating your `$data` array like this:

```
$data = [];
foreach($request->input('option_id') as $id) { 
    $data[$id] = [ 'name' => $request->input('data')[$id] ];
}
```

Comment: Im trying what you suggested but dont know how to achieve it :( i have edited the above with how i build up the array

Comment: updated answer, try building out your `$data` array like that.